# Is it possible to add md-autofocus support to ng-show?

Tags: angularjs, angular-material, ng-show

I have a form which I show/hide dynamically on my page using ng-show. Is it possible to somehow add support for md-autofocus to ng-show?

Comment: As it clearly suggests that `md-autofocus` only works with `$mdDialog`, `$mdBottomSheet` and `$mdSidenav`. Check this offical doc link. https://material.angularjs.org/1.0.4/api/directive/mdAutofocus

Comment: @nextt1, that is exactly why my question has 'add' word in it.